# Shopware 6 translate customer custom field

Tags: symfony, shopware

we have a custom import script for customers.
Now we added a custom field to the customer (string/text field).

We need to display a custom payment term hint on the checkout page for each customer.
Unfortunately we are not able to identify a way to translate the custom fields of the customer entity.

This is how we do it with the custom fields of the product entity:

```
$customFieldsArr['translations'][$languageId]['customFields'][$customFieldTechnicalName] = $value;

$productData = [
                    'active' => $active,
                    'name' => $namesTranslationArr,
                    'description' => $descriptionsTranslationArr,
                    'stock' => $stock,
                    'tax' => [
                        'id' => $taxId
                    ],
                    'price' => [
                        [
                            'currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY,
                            'gross' => $gross,
                            'net' => $gross / (1 + ($taxRate / 100.0)),
                            'linked' => true
                        ]
                    ],
                    'productNumber' => $productNumber,
                    'categories' => $categoryIds,
                    'visibilities' => $salesChannelIds,
                    'ean' => $ean,
                    'manufacturerNumber' => $manufacturerNumber,
                    'maxPurchase' => $maxPurchase,
                    'minPurchase' => $minPurchase,
                    'purchaseSteps' => $purchaseSteps,
                    'shippingFree' => $shippingFree,
                    'markAsTopseller' => $markAsTopseller,
                    'purchaseUnit' => $purchaseUnit,
                    'weight' => $weight,
                    'width' => $width,
                    'height' => $height,
                    'length' => $length,
                    'packUnit' => $packUnitTranslationArr,
                    'packUnitPlural' => $packUnitPluralTranslationArr,
                    'metaTitle' => $metaTitlesTranslationArr,
                    'metaDescription' => $metaDescriptionsTranslationArr,
                    'keywords' => $keywordsTranslationArr,
                    'unitId' => $unitId,
                    'referenceUnit' => $referenceUnit,
                    'deliveryTimeId' => $deliveryTimeId,
                    'restockTime' => $restockTime,
                    'isCloseout' => $isCloseout,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'parentProductNumber' => $parentProductNumber
                ];

                $productData = array_merge($customFieldsArr, $productData);

$this->productRepository->upsert($productData , $context);
```

If we try to do the same with the customer entity the translation is not saved.

So what we tried is the following:

```
 $customFieldsArr['translations'][$languageId]['customFields'][$customFieldTechnicalName] = $value;
$customerData = [
                    'customerNumber' => $customerNumber,
                    'active' => $active,
                    'title' => $title,
                    'salutationId' => $salutationId,
                    'firstName' => $firstname,
                    'lastName' => $lastname,
                    'company' => $company,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'birthday' => $birthday,
                    'salesChannelId' => $salesChannelId,
                    'vatIds' => $vatId,
                    'groupId' => $customerGroupId
                ];

                $customerData = array_merge($customFieldsArr, $customerData);

                    $this->customerRepository->upsert($customerData , $context);
```

This is not working and the translations are not saved to the customer entity.
We can only do it like that:

```
$customFieldsArr['customFields'][$customFieldTechnicalName] = $value;
```

But with this piece of code we are not able to define a translation.

Is there an error in the code / idea above or is it in shopware 6 simply not possible to translate the customer custom fields?

Comment: Customer's custom fields are not translated as product's custom fields so you can't save translations for them in the database. What i think, you can same some key to you custom fields and after that use it as a part of the snippet. So you can add snippets` keys which are dependent on your vaue.

Comment: Ok, so it is simply missing - if you cannot switch the language in the backend it makes no sense to be able to create a custom field that should be translatable for the customer.

Comment: Now it is possible to switch the language in the backend/administration - unfortunately there is still no translations array available in the customer entity - shopware uses the context to translate the custom field - in other entities you can add the association "translations" and use that to translate the custom fields...